# Using xamarin studio for windows 7 desktop application development

Tags: c#, xamarin, windows-7, desktop-application

Is it possible to use Xamarin Studio (not Visual Studio) to develop Windows 7 desktop applications?
The reason I am asking is that I'd like to use it for IOS/OS x/Android development but I also need the app to run on Windows 7.

Comment: This question should not be asked on SO. SO is for specific programming questions.

Comment: @Progo, not sure what you think is non-specific about this question...

Comment: To the OP, sure, you can develop all those application types, but all of the UI frameworks for each platform are mutually incompatible.  (Though you *can* use Xamarin.Forms for cross-platform UI support between Android and IOS)

Comment: @Kirk, I understand. My plan is to use xamarin.forms for ios/android/os x and do a separate UI for W7. Thanks.

Comment: Xamarin.Forms is abstraction for iOS, Android & WP8. For the desktop WinForms and GTK# work cross-platform for Windows, OSX & Linux/*nix. If you have a copy of Visual Studio I would use it for Windows development though and share the PCL code/projects with your mobile applications. Well designed MVVM code can be easily shared between different UI front-ends.

Comment: @SKall Understood. Will follow this approach. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It is possible.
Project type -> C# -> Console & WinForm Application is avaiable.

Comment: Can we use this windows applications in MAC OS ?

Comment: Also is it possible to test and develop Windows10 Desktop application from Mac using Xamarin?